# "Fractal" Spheres are partially black without alpha (Cycles)

Tags: objects, transparency

I use fractal spheres as a quick alternative to explosion domains.
However, since I switched to Cycles, these objects appear partially black without alpha.
I tried recalculating normals, using other materials, and disabling shadows, but none solved the issue.

[image: A Fractal sphere without alpha]

Comment: Hi, entertainment animations .. could you confirm, here, if @GordonBrinkmann's suggestion has worked for you? If it hasn't we'll need more detail; maybe share a minimal version of the problem on https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Although I had to set my transparency samples to 12, it did work. Thanks!

Comment: @entertainmentanimations You mean bounces, not samples I guess ;) I have mine at 128. It's costing not as much render times as it seems and so I'm quite confident that I'm getting problems with transparency very rarely.